# Fetch all sub queries from a bigger query in python

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Is there a way to fetch all the SQL sub queries (in SQL Server) from one larger query or stored procedure in python?

For example:

```
Select column1, column2
From 
    (select columnX, columnY 
     from table1) 
Where 
    column1 exists in (select columnP from table2)
```

I'm creating a tool in Python to split up all sub queries and store them individually in a list like below and execute them in the next stage.

```
List[0] -> "select columnX, columnY from table1

List[1] -> "select columnP from table2"
```

Thank you

Comment: I am fairly sure this is something you would need to write on your own process because you would need to make sure all of the subqueries were written consistently for your parser.

Comment: When it comes to getting data out of a database, it's usually better to think like a SQL developer than like a Python (or other language) programmer. You'll be doing a lot of unnecessary processing, eliminating the benefits of your indexes, crippling the SQL server's internal optimizer and beating up on your network. SQL dev usually aims for set-based operations that the SQL Server is geared for. Can it be done? Yes. Should it be done? Probably not.

Comment: @Shawn, Thanks for the detailed response. I'm planning to build an application to find out which part of the subquery is processing for long time, maybe the one which throws a possible error. I'll further develop it to display the long processing part in the stored procedure full of sub queries. Are you aware of any forum post or document to achieve that? Any related answers will put me in the right path.

Comment: @user3862986 I think you may be looking in the wrong place. Taking the individual pieces of a query and trying to time them in Python wont really tell you which subqueries are problem queries. The best place to find query performance metrics is within the SQL server itself. SQL Server has Profiler built in, which might give you some metrics. And it has a bunch of built in functions that give you insight into your db. Look at DMVs. But there are also a ton of other monitoring tools that might give you more sight into what you're trying to do. Performance tuning is an art form in and of itself.

Comment: All that said, if performance is a problem, it might be worthwhile to invest in one of the monitoring tools. SentryOne  Plan Explorer (https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer) will give you some great metrics. Or, if it's more complex, it might also be worthwhile to hire someone who can seriously tune your queries. I highly recommend Aaron Bertrand and Pinal Dave. Both of them are pretty brilliant. And there are other really good ones. You might be able to look around your local area or contact your local SQL User Group or PASS Chapter.